# Recover data from partition overwritten by swap partition

Tags: partitioning, swap, data-recovery

I've just reinstalled Ubuntu, and I chose a partition full of data as a swap area. I didn't realize that the swap area would overwrite my files.

Can I recover my partition or my data now?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do, is take a dd image of your swap, bit by bit:

```
dd if=/your/swap of=/path/to/file.dd
```

"Your swap" is usually a separate partition. To find out which one do:

```
fdisk -l
```

once you obtain the .dd file, install autopsy:

```
 apt-get install autopsy
```

run it as root in your terminal, and open a browser as instructed.

Create a case in autopsy, and try recovering data in this way.
It may be complicated, but first secure the .dd file, then try forensic techniques recovering files. You may want to read up on autopsy as a forensic tool for data recovery.

Comment: I've searched how can I use autopsy and I get this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

but the say that this apply for old 7.04 7.10 8.04, so can I use this way since I have 11.10

Comment: and I'm totally new to Ubuntu, so could you be more specific about the directory (if=/your/swap)

Comment: can you show me your output for this command:
$ sudo fdisk -l

Comment: I'm now using Windows, because I don't want to lose more data, so tell me what to do please

Comment: If you're on windows, the download FTK Imager free from accessdata.com, and try recover deleted files. You first need to mount the hard drive, then lookup deleted entries. You still could recoved deleted files. Best luck!

Comment: I thought that there is a command can make this easily, just to make the swap partition as a normal partition

Comment: That's impossible, because the swap partition was already used, and some data in there are overwritten, so other data recovery means are needed. Try den4uk's tip.

Comment: now I need tutorial how to use FTK Imager !

Comment: can you give me some tips please